# Boost Libraries not linking properly on Windows

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14

I've a large project which was originally built on Macos, that I'm trying to get compiling on Windows. The makefile for the project is as follows:

```
CC=C:/cygwin64/bin/g++.exe


BASE_FLAGS = -std=c++14

LDFLAGS = -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0/include -I/opt/local/include -I include/

LLIBFLAGS = -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/lib

LINKFLAGS = -lboost_thread -lboost_system -l boost_filesystem -l boost_regex -ll -lm

FLAGS = $(BASE_FLAGS) $(LLIBFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS)

rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

SRCS := $(call rwildcard,src/,*.cpp) $(call rwildcard,src/,*.c) 

mac:
    cd src; bison -d parse.y --debug -t; flex lex.l
    time ./runscripts.sh
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o main.out $(SRCS)


BASE_FLAGS_WIN = -std=gnu++11

LDFLAGS_WIN = -I include/ -I C:\Users\elllz\Downloads\boost_1_69_0

LLIBFLAGS_WIN = -LC:\Users\elllz\Downloads\boost_1_69_0\stage\lib

LINKFLAGS_WIN =  -lm -lboost_system -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread

FLAGS_WIN = $(BASE_FLAGS_WIN) $(LDFLAGS_WIN)  $(LLIBFLAGS_WIN)  $(LINKFLAGS_WIN) 

win:
    bison -d .\src\parse.y -t -g
    flex .\src\lex.l 
    .\scripts\ALL_HEADER_TOKENS.bat
    cp .\parse.tab.h .\src\parse.tab.h
    cp .\parse.tab.c .\src\parse.tab.c
    cp .\lex.yy.c .\src\lex.yy.c
    rm .\parse.tab.h .\parse.tab.c .\lex.yy.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS_WIN)  $(SRCS)
```

Note that the first second is the (working) macos target, and the later is the Windows target. When trying to link boost on Windows, I keep getting a plethora of undefined reference errors, like such:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/cc1jUol1.o:FileVerification.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE[_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE]+0x15): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/cc1jUol1.o:FileVerification.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE[_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE]+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/cc1jUol1.o:FileVerification.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE[_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE]+0x32): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _mbstate_t> const&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/cc1jUol1.o:FileVerification.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE[_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE]+0x32): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _mbstate_t> const&)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/cc1jUol1.o:FileVerification.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem6existsERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem6existsERKNS0_4pathE]+0x1e): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/cc1jUol1.o:FileVerification.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem6existsERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem6existsERKNS0_4pathE]+0x1e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/cc1jUol1.o:FileVerification.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem15is_regular_fileERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem15is_regular_fileERKNS0_4pathE]+0x1e): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/cc1jUol1.o:FileVerification.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem15is_regular_fileERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem15is_regular_fileERKNS0_4pathE]+0x1e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/ccbzCEFH.o:Token.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_14c_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE[_ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_14c_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE]+0x7e): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106900::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::c_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/ccbzCEFH.o:Token.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_14c_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE[_ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_14c_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE]+0x7e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::re_detail_106900::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::c_regex_traits<char>
> >::match()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/ccbzCEFH.o:Token.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_14c_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j[_ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_14c_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j]+0x31): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::c_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/elllz/AppData/Local/Temp/ccbzCEFH.o:Token.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_14c_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j[_ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_14c_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j]+0x31): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::c_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
```

That's only a snippet, all the information I can find says it's a boost linking problem, but I can't pin it down for the life of me. I'm compiling boost 1.69.0 with the commands:

`.\boostrap.bat`

`./bjam`

`./bjam install`

In a similar manner to the instructions found [here](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2012/getting-started-with-the-boost-libraries-in-cygwin/). I've tried jsut about everything I can think of, as well as spent a lot of time recompiling boost, so any help you might be able to offer would be greatly appreciated!

Things I have tried:

- Checking the libaries do exist in /stage/lib, they do, as .a and .dll.a files.
- Moving the entire boost folder into a relative path of my build folder, in case I was specifying the link / include folders wrong.
- Recompiling boost with a host of options, I can't come close to recalling them all.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you may have multiple issues...

Your `makefile` specifies different versions of the `boost` libraries: `1.69.0` and `1.68.0`

```
LDFLAGS = -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0/include -I/opt/local/include -I include/

LLIBFLAGS = -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/lib
```

It could be as simple as that.

However, on a `Windows` machine, the command:

```
.\boostrap.bat
```

normally assumes building the `boost` libraries using `Visual Studio`.
So depending upon where you built the `boost` libraries from, you may have built `Visual Studio` lib files, not `g++` lib files. You can tell from the library file names:

```
// gcc, actually mingw73: mgw73
libboost_filesystem-mgw73-mt-x64-1_69.dll.a

// msvc 2017: vc141
boost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64-1_69.lib
```

It sounds like yours are correct, but you can specify the `g++` compiler explicitly when building `boost`, e.g.:

```
.\boostrap.bat gcc
```

Finally, it's difficult to maintain cross platform `makefiles`, especially with `boost`.
I recommend using [cmake](https://cmake.org/) instead.